# Is there a semisimple Hopf algebra Grothendieck equivalent to a strictly weak one?

Tags: ct.category-theory, qa.quantum-algebra, hopf-algebras, fusion-categories

By Corollary 2.22 in *[On fusion categories](https://doi.org/10.4007/annals.2005.162.581)* (by Pavel Etingof, Dmitri Nikshych and Viktor Ostrik) any fusion category is equivalent to the category of finite dimensional representations of a semisimple weak Hopf algebra.

Two fusion categories are called *Grothendieck equivalent* if their Grothendieck rings are equivalent.
Two semisimple weak Hopf algebras are *Grothendieck equivalent* if their fusion categories are so.

**Question**: Is there a semisimple Hopf algebra Grothendieck equivalent to a strictly weak one?
(we are specifically interested in the finite dimensional complex case)

IOW: Does the fusion ring distinguish the non-weak and the strictly weak cases?

Note that there is a sufficient condition for a fusion ring to be in the strictly weak case: it is the existence of a basic element with a non-integer Perron-Frobenius dimension. So the non-existence of such non-integer Perron-Frobenius dimension is a necessary condition for the non-weak case.

Comment: About Cor. 2.22, can the semisimple weak Hopf algebra always be taken finite dimensional?